# Native translation of dex formatted code in android

Tags: android, operating-system, native, dalvik, dex

For my static analysis I want to know one thing. My question is while we are running an android app does android OS translates the optimized Dex instructions to native instructions on the go? If so can someone shed some light on the scenario?

Answer (score 0):

> android OS translates the optimized Dex instructions to native instructions on the go?

Almost **yes**

According to [Wikipedia: Dalvik (software)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29) as of Android 2.2, `Dalvik` has a [just-in-time compiler (JIT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) and according to [Wikipedia: Android Runtime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Runtime) `ART` introduces use of the [ahead-of-time (AOT) compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahead-of-time_compilation) by performing it upon the installation of an application.